# Generate the Convolution Matrix of 2D Kernel for Convolution Shape of `same`

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision, convolution

I want to find a convolution matrix for a certain 2D kernel $ H $.
For example, for image `Img` of size $ m \times n $ , I want (in MATALB):

```
T * Img = reshape(conv2(Img, H, 'same'), [], 1);
```

Where `T` is the convolution matrix and `same` means the Convolution Shape (Output Size) matched the input size.

Theoretically, H should be converted to a toeplitz matrix, I'm using the MATLAB function `convmtx2()`:

```
T = convmtx2(H, m, n);
```

Yet `T` is of size $ (m+2) (n+2) \times (mn) $ as MATLAB's `convmtx2` generates a convolution matrix which matches Convolution Shape of `full`.

Is there a way to generate the Convolution Matrix which matches using `conv2()` with the `same` convolution shape parameter?

Comment: Are you looking simply to get the same resultant T*Img or you would like to use T for a different purpose?

Comment: I edited your code and maths so it looks more atractive. You can do this yourself on future questions. For Latex editing use $$.

Comment: Related question - https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17418.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot test this on my computer because I do not have the convtmx2 function, here is what the MATLAB help says:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/convmtx2.html

`T = convmtx2(H,m,n)` returns the convolution matrix `T` for the matrix `H`. If `X` is an m-by-n matrix, then `reshape(T*X(:),size(H)+[m n]-1)` is the same as `conv2(X,H)`.

This would get the same resulting convolution of `conv2(X,H)` but then you would still have to pull out the correct piece of the convolution.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE, and this is a great answer!

Comment: I think that sometimes one needs the actual matrix to analyze it (The adjoint operator, the inverse, etc...). Hence this method won't work (Unless you start removing rows form the matrix which will be slow as it is Sparse).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function which solves this in my [StackExchange Codes StackOverflow Q2080835 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Have a look at `StackOverflow\Q2080835` folder for a file named `CreateImageConvMtx()`).
Actually the function can support any convolution shape you'd like - `full`, `same` and `valid`.

The code is as following:

```
function [ mK ] = CreateImageConvMtx( mH, numRows, numCols, convShape )

CONVOLUTION_SHAPE_FULL  = 1;
CONVOLUTION_SHAPE_SAME  = 2;
CONVOLUTION_SHAPE_VALID = 3;

switch(convShape)
    case(CONVOLUTION_SHAPE_FULL)
        % Code for the 'full' case
        convShapeString = 'full';
    case(CONVOLUTION_SHAPE_SAME)
        % Code for the 'same' case
        convShapeString = 'same';
    case(CONVOLUTION_SHAPE_VALID)
        % Code for the 'valid' case
        convShapeString = 'valid';
end

mImpulse = zeros(numRows, numCols);

for ii = numel(mImpulse):-1:1
    mImpulse(ii)    = 1; %<! Create impulse image corresponding to i-th output matrix column
    mTmp            = sparse(conv2(mImpulse, mH, convShapeString)); %<! The impulse response
    cColumn{ii}     = mTmp(:);
    mImpulse(ii)    = 0;
end

mK = cell2mat(cColumn);


end
```

Enjoy...