# How can we determine the channel impulse response using correlation process from the spectrum of the signal?

Tags: signal-analysis

I am sending the pulsed signal from the transmitter antenna, and at the receiver side, I captured the received signal in the time domain, and also in the spectrum of the signal. How can I get the Channel Impulse Response (CIR) using the correlation process?

Comment: Please see my answer here which outlines how to do this using the Wiener-Hopf equations (to determine an equalizer for the channel or the channel impulse response itself): https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31318/compensating-loudspeaker-frequency-response-in-an-audio-signal