# Sound Source Location

Tags: python, localization

I have four microphones which I want to use to locate the direction of an audio source. Is there any Python module that implements an algorithm that, given the recordings of the four microphones, will give me a vector pointing to/angles of the audio source?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i don't have any Python anything.  but i am curious, how are your 4 microphones arranged geometrically?

Comment: Their geometry is [[0,0,r],[-r,0,0],[0,0,-r],[0,r,0]].

Comment: i might suggest as a tetrahedron.  that would be the 4 corners of a cube such that none are adjacent.  i think it might be $[1,0,0], \ [0,1,0], \ [0,0,1], \ [1,1,1]$ .

Comment: Sadly, I can not rearrange them.

Comment: it's an arrangement that will measure elevation angle best since the spacing of the microphones along the $z$-axis is $2r$.  if you place a source at $[0,0,0]$, that should be equidistant from all microphones.  do you get identical signals in all 4 channels?

Comment: do you know how to do cross-correlation? $$R_{xy}[k] = \sum_n x[n]\,y[n+k] $$ a maximum of $R_{xy}[k]$ will indicate the value of $k$ corresponding to the path length difference of the distances of the source to microphone $x$ and microphone $y$.

Comment: We have never done that, but I do believe that we would get the same signal across all mics. That won't be a problem though, as the microphones are really close together (they are actually hydrophones, and their distance is really small).

Comment: I read about it on wikipedia, but I couldn't understand it very well. What is exactly x[n] and y[n+k] and would I do it once for every mic combination?

Comment: yes, you do it for every mic pairing.  and the offset (or "lag") $k$ that gives you the maximum cross-correlation tells you the difference in path lengths of the sound source to the two microphones (you have to also know the speed of sound).  doing this for each pair of microphones will give you a set of equations that can be solved to find the location of the source relative to the microphone array.  there's some geometry and trigonometry involved.

Comment: with 4 microphones placed **not** all on the same plane, you are able to not only locate the direction of the source, but the distance to the source, if the source is not too far away.

Comment: Do you have any links that shows all the math or a sample matlab code of how it can be done?

Comment: here's a beginning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_location#Time_difference_of_arrival

Comment: This may help: I used this approach to determine the effective channel between two microphones; if you solve for the channel coefficients between the microphones, you can convert the phase vs frequency response to delay (relationship is a derivative) and from that triangulate the source with a least mean square solution. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31318/compensating-loudspeaker-frequency-response-in-an-audio-signal

Comment: Thanks man, I'll study these links and see if I can find the sound source position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish I could say that there are 2 different approaches to determining the direction of a source relative to some phase center of an array but that wouldn’t be correct.

Firstly I don’t think there is a Python module that does it generally because there are no algorithms that are completely general.

Having said that there are not 2 general classes of algorithms, I’m going to ignore what I just said.  There is beamforming and there is cross correlation.

Beamforming seeks to use coherent gain to determine direction.

Cross Correlation seeks to determine the relative delays between the sensors and then pick the best solution.

Both categories are based on the principle that a propagating wave can be described by a wave front which is a surface in 3 or 2 dimensions of stationary phase.  In a homogeneous 3 d free space, a point source the wavefront  consists of expanding spheres where the amplitude drops off as $1/r$. Far enough away from the point source, the wavefront is sufficiently flat to assume a plane wave.

So in a real problem you have to make some assumptions about the propagating wavefronts.  We can also have non radiating field components near the source.

The most typically standard approach is to assume plane waves from point sources impinging on your sensors.  There are other kinds of assumptions that can be made like near point sources having wavefronts that have some curvature but you only have 4 sensors.

In beamforming we apply a set of delays to each received signal based on the assumption that it came from some direction and stack them up and sum them.  The set of delays from the correct direction would produce the greatest coherent gain. This means that you have to form a lot of beams for a lot of proposed directions.  Being off a little bit means that the estimated direction would be off a little as well. Beamforming is expensive in real time. Old fashioned RADAR solved the problem by scanning with a rotating parabolic antenna. In SONAR, rotating parabolas are mechanically undesirable and forming multiple beams is the better way to go.

The cross correlation method goes after the delays but you have to do all pairs and then you need to figure out which direction produced those delays.

There is something called split aperture beamforming which is a combination of the two.

When you have more than one source the basic ideas mostly hold but there are issues that are best left for a book or 2 or 10.

If your sensors are too close together, there are problems.

If your source is distributed some adjustments will help.

One good aspect of these problems is the Bessel Fourier relationship because like Fourier series in time,  an arbitrary wavefront at a temporal frequency can be described by a sum of plane waves.

There is a very very large literature on direction finding. I sometimes wonder if there are more papers than there are actual arrays but that is getting less true (not actually true) as time goes on.

Comment: This was very informative. Do you have any links that go more into the math of the three methods you described, like, how do I tell from which direction the sound came from the delay? I need to find one source in a 3D space and I am confused on how to get the elevation and azimuth.

Comment: books are better than links  Nielsen, Richard O. Sonar signal processing. Artech House, Inc., 1991.