# Allan varinace/ two-sample variance plot interpretation

Tags: noise

I am using the following code to generate an allen variance plot from some accelerometer data

https://github.com/nmayorov/allan-variance/blob/master/allan_variance.py

It seems a sound implementation looking at Allan variance definitions I can find online

How do I interpret this graph?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of drift (non-stationary data). The horizontal axis is the averaging time $\tau$, and the vertical axis is the standard deviation (ADEV) of differences between successive blocks of data each $\tau$ long, and separated by $\tau$ seconds. If the data had a stationary white noise statistic, the ADEV would instead be going down at the square root of tau. For more on ADEV please see these posts:

[Bias instability in Gyroscopes : AVER / ADEV](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54078/bias-instability-in-gyroscopes-aver-adev/54081#54081)

[How to interpret Allan Deviation plot for gyroscope?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53970/how-to-interpret-allan-deviation-plot-for-gyroscope/53993#53993)

[Is Allan variance still relevant?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79121/is-allan-variance-still-relevant/79124#79124)

Comment: indeed, my data was not stationary. I guess I should look again at this plot after taking first temporal difference of the data to make them stationary? when doing that, indeed the slope changes to negative

Comment: That is what the ADEV computation does.. .the point is that gyroscopes drift and are not stationary. The ADEV is very useful to quantify and compare non-stationary processes since it will do that difference you describe, so you don't need to do that first.