# What does Allan variance really means?

Tags: statistics, sensor

Let a sensor (e.g. accelerometer) with a combination of white gaussian noise and random walk noise. 
The loglog plot that is usually shown as function of a time parameter, affine decreasing for a white gaussian noise and affine increasing for a random walk.
What does it mean? 
Can we read from the graph the variance of the gaussian noise? 
I cannot really grasp the intuition behind it: how does the Allan variance help to get more information about the noise than a PSD or some cross-correlation?

Comment: I also went into details of Allan Variance and ADEV (Allan Deviation) here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53123/what-determines-the-accuracy-of-the-phase-result-in-a-dft-bin/53158#53158

Comment: You could get it from the horse's mouth: http://www.allanstime.com/Publications/DWA/Science_Timekeeping/TheScienceOfTimekeeping.pdf