# Cross Correlation as Noise Reduction, is this possible?

Tags: noise, cross-correlation

If I have two sensor measuring the same signal but from two different locations from the source, and I get two different readings of the signal, each with slightly different noise.

Is there a way to use the cross correlation of the signals to get a third signal which represents the components of the signal which are common across both measurements?

The reason I ask is that I have tried to do this, and I can get the cross correlation signal, but I can't figure out how to use this to get back to something that looks like the original signal, see below [image]

i.e. How can  I get something which looks like a mix of the **green** and **blue** signals from the **red** one?

Comment: that's exactly what *matched filters* do!

Comment: when you say same signal, do they have the same bandwidth? is there a known delay between the two?

Comment: They have the same bandwidth, and there could be a possible very slight delay just because one might be a little bit further away from the source than the other, but it's not known

Comment: have you tried adding them?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you're suggesting, do you mean I try to average each point? I have not tried this but I will certainly give it a go

Comment: How about considering an approach such as this one, using your two signals to determine the related cross-channel and then once aligned combining them to maximize your SNR (+3 dB): https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31318/compensating-loudspeaker-frequency-response-in-an-audio-signal/31326#31326