# FIR filter for flipping the phase in negative phase

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, digital-filters, filtering, least-squares

I have built up a FIR filter based on [**least square approach**](https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/iselesni/EL713/firls/firls.pdf).

I deploy the IDFT matrix $$F_{inv}$$ in above document page 7 and the desired response for compensated is H_F, the objective is
$$
    min_{h_F} || F_{inv} * h_{F} -  H_{F} ||
$$
h_F is a complex number obtained by above approach.

I plot the frequency response of the designed filter response and the target response for compensation. Both diagrams' x-axis are frequency however the y-axis is gain(dB) and phase(360 degree) separately.

Blue line in below graph is the target response to compensate and the other orange line is the compensated response. As they are more similar, the target will be achieved.

The gain is almost approached
[![Gain response is almost approached by the cmp gain line][2]][2]

However, the phase is inverses in negative frequency
[![Phase is sill unapproached by the cmp phase line][3]][3]

Is there any idea about ***how to flip the phase in negative frequency***?

According to [**least square approach**](https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/iselesni/EL713/firls/firls.pdf), I have tried the IDFT in page 7  to inverse the negative frequency by complex conjugate operation on the exponential basis.

Any idea or paper is welcome, thanks for your reading

Comment: This is potentially a bug in your code. If the impulse response of the  filter is real as in $\in \mathbb{R}$ then the phase at negative frequencies MUST be the negative of the phase at positive frequencies. If that's not the case, your filter must be complex.

Comment: Exactly, my filter coefficients are complex. How can I fix this problem ?  OR I need to reformulate it ?

Comment: You need to put a "real"  constraint into your least squares solver.

Comment: @Hilmar Did you have any idea or paper to constrain the solution for building real number coefficient ? I have found this one [linear phase real number constraint](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/808.php#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I learned myself from our DSP.StackExchange King MattL with this more detailed and [interesting post](https://mattsdsp.blogspot.com/2022/10/design-of-iir-allpass-filters-least.html) at his own blog, we can restrict any least squares solution to be real as follows:

Starting with generalized overdetermined matrix equation leading toward a least squares solution, given as:

$$y = A c \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Where $y$ is a $D \times 1$ column vector of known values, $A$ is a $D \times N$ matrix of known values, and $c$ is the $N \times 1$ column vector of unknown filter coefficients to be solved. To be an overdetermined system appropriate for a least square solution, $D>>N$.

Which in general form we would solve for $c$ by multiplying rectangular matrix $A$ by its inverse to create a square invertible matrix, isolating $c$ for the solution as follows:

Multiply both sides by the complex conjugate transpose of $A$ to get a square matrix $A^TA$ which can be inverted:
$$A^Ty = A^TA c $$

Multiply both sides by the inverse of $A^TA$ to isolate $c$:
$$(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty = (A^TA)^{-1}A^TA c $$

Resulting in the least squares solution for $c$ as:
$$c = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty  \tag{2}\label{2}$$

As done above, this would result in a complex solution for $c$.

I explain with more visual examples of how the above matrices can be constructed, specifically for the case of a least squares equalizer and the "Wiener-Hopf" equation, at [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31318/compensating-loudspeaker-frequency-response-in-an-audio-signal/31326#31326), however above is the construction for all generalized least squares solutions.

As I learned from MattL, to restrict to real only coefficients, we can first expand equation \ref{1} as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}y_R\\y_I\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}A_R\\A_I\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}c_R\end{bmatrix} \tag{3}\label{3}$$

Where the complex values in the $D \times 1$ column vector $y$ are converted to a $2D \times 1$ column vector by first listing the real components of $y$  as $y_R$ followed by the imaginary components of $y$ as $y_I$ resulting in an all real $2D \times 1$ column vector. Similarly the complex values in the $D \times N$ rectangular matrix A are converted to an all real $2D \times N$ matrix using the real ($A_R$) and imaginary ($A_I$) values in $A$.

To understand how equation \ref{3} results in real only coefficients, consider first the full complex product with complex coefficients:

$$(A_R+jA_I)(c_R+jc_I) = (A_Rc_R-A_Ic_I) + j(A_Ic_R+A_Rc_I)$$

If we instead restricted $c$ to just be real only by making $c_I=0$ in the equation above, we would instead have:

$$(A_R+jA_I)(c_R) = (A_Rc_R) + j(A_Ic_R)$$

Which can be expressed in matrix form as follows, ordered to show similarity to equation \ref{3}:

$$\begin{bmatrix}A_Rc_R\\jA_Ic_R\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}A_R\\jA_I\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}c_R\end{bmatrix} \tag{4}\label{4}$$

We can drop the $j$ that appears on both sides of the equation, since keeping it or removing it will not change the result as a set of linear equations. Thus we can proceed from equation \ref{3} to solve for the real coefficients $c$ as was done for the complex coefficients in equation \ref{2} using the same process as follows:

$$\begin{bmatrix}c_R\end{bmatrix} = \left(\begin{bmatrix}A_R\\A_I\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}A_R\\A_I\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}A_R\\A_I\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}y_R\\y_I\end{bmatrix}  \tag{5}\label{5}$$

Comment: Pretty appreciate!!! it's useful and implementable.

Comment: Bischen Nice tutorial of your previous work in DSP.StackExchange. I just found that I learned your constructed basis from your blog.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the honor ... :) [This blog post](https://mattsdsp.blogspot.com/2022/10/fir-filters-with-prescribed-magnitude.html) explains the general least squares design of FIR filters, including the constraints to obtain a real-valued solution. There's also Matlab/Octave code.

Comment: @simonLiao that is MattL’s blog I was referring to, not mine!