Recovering impulse responses and inter-channel delay from asynchronous stereo recordings
Let's suppose we have a stereo loudspeaker system and we want to measure the impulse responses of both channels using logarithmic sweeps and a microphone. The measurement system is "asynchronous," meaning that recording and playback don't start at the same time (e.g., we press the record button and then play the sweeps after an unknown delay).
How can we recover the impulse responses and the inter-channel delay from the recorded file? In some software, the test signal used for measuring a stereo system consists of a sweep on the left channel, followed by a sweep on the right channel, and then a repeated sweep on the left channel. What is the purpose of repeating the left channel sweep?

This may help provide an example of implementing Marcus' good answer: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31318/compensating-loudspeaker-frequency-response-in-an-audio-signal/31326#31326


How can we recover the impulse responses and the inter-channel delay from the recorded file?

Correlation. You emit a wideband, known signal (e.g., a chirp, but this can also be pseudorandom white noise), you correlate your recording with the same, you get the convolution of the autocorrelation function of that signal with the impulse response. A properly designed signal will have a close-to-dirac shape, so you essentially get the impulse response.
You can't know the absolute delay before the "first" path reaches the microphone, but that doesn't matter, usually. What matters is the time span before the first and the last significant path.
Inter-channel delay is simply a matter of knowing how much time you've left between playing your test signal on the left, and playing it on the right channel, and comparing that to how much the correlation peaks in your recording are apart.
Note that there's no inherent reason why you couldn't play two orthogonal signals, one on each channel, at the same time, and correlate with each at the same time (it's probably not done because nonlinearities are a thing in audio, and these might kill your orthogonality). It's what CDMA is based on.
